# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x\log(x)$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

Is it true that:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x\log_{n}(x) = 0 \quad ; \quad n \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: is this $\log_{10} x$ or  $\log_{e} x$

Comment: This should be in your calculus textbook.

Comment: @Arjang Since $\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$ it doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: I think in US $\log=\ln$ when the base is not specified. At least this is what it means in all software that I know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log x}{1/x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}-x=0$$

Answer (score -1):

**hint**: Write $x = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: How does that help?